# Angular JS Inner Html for Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, innerhtml, ng-bind-html

I am developing my application with angularjs and ionic,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p ng-bind-html="{{itemID}}"></p>

</div>
```

I would like to change this to angularjs like innerHTML,

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "My name is:John Doe";
});
</script>
```

This is not because it needs to write itemid instead of $scope.myText.

How can I do it uniquely as above ?

Comment: $scope.myText = "My name is:John Doe";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
controller.js

```
$scope.myText={};


    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$itemID) {
        $scope.myText{$itemID} = "My name is:John Doe";
    });
```

html page

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p ng-bind-html="myText[$itemID]"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code

```
<p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>
```